# How to map from query string to SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

So I have as search endpoint

```
[HttpGet("search")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromQuery] string query)
```

that returns a list of users from the cosmosDb based on email, name etc.

The problem is that I don't know how to convert the query string into an SQL query or LINQ statement. I have googled for hours, but I can't find any examples, but it just seems weird if I have to write my own query parser?

Comment: Can you give an example of what's passed as a value for `query`? Is it just a search term (e.g. "sam") or is it an actual query (e.g. `SELECT * FROM ...`)?

Comment: I imagine something like /users/search?query=firstname%DLucy&lastname%DJohnson

Comment: otherwise you can use odata controller to handle complex query without having to translate the query string yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example value of `query` in your comment, I guess you actually mean something like `/users/search?query=firstname%3DLucy%26lastname%3DJohnson` (note the `%3D` instead of `%D` and `%26` instead of `&`). The decoded value of this would be `firstname=Lucy&lastname=Johnson`. In this case you'd have kind of a query string inside the value of your query string's `query` parameter.

One solution would be to get rid of the `query` parameter and just use the parameters of your actual query as normal query string parameters.

For example:

```
// URL with query string:
// /users/search?firstName=Lucy&lastname=Johnson

// Matching controller method
[HttpGet("search")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(
  [FromQuery] string firstName = null, 
  [FromQuery] string lastName = null)
{
  // use the firstName and lastName variables to put together some 
  // SQL as a string or include them in some linq
}
```

With the solution described above, you don't have to parse anything as the values of your query would be parsed out of the box by asp.net. You would however have to put together the query to the database yourself.

If you want to stick to your original design and have one single `query` parameter that itself is a query string you can do the following:

```
// URL with query string:
// https://localhost:5000/search?query%3DLucy&26lastname%3DJohnson

// Matching controller method
[HttpGet("search")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(
  [FromQuery] string query)
{
  var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
  // ...or, depending on what version of .NET you're using:
  // var parsed = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(query);
  var firstName = parsed["firstName"];
  var lastName = parsed["lastName"];
  // use the firstName and lastName variables to put together some 
  // SQL as a string or include them in some linq
}
```

Comment: So there's no way of avoiding making a custom search endpoint for every query? If the user wants to filter by email for instance

Comment: A separate search endpoint isn't necessary for every query. You'd just add email as yet another parameter to the `Search()` method just like `firstName` and `lastName`. All of these parameters are nullable strings which means they're optional in the query string.